# How to Access Hidden Power and Processor Options in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, power-management, powercfg, guid

What means are there to access and change hidden power and processor options in Windows 10?

- A way to find information on hidden globally unique identifier (GUID) power and processor options.
- A way to configure them for testing purposes.

---

The following elevated CMD command only shows visible GUID's from the power options window:

```
powercfg /q
```

[image: Windows-10-Power-GUID]

*There seemed to be a discrepancy with [normal powercfg exports](https://forums.evga.com/m/tm.aspx?m=2820975&fp=5&p=3) on the net and [tweaked configurations](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/43655-create-custom-power-plan-windows-10-a-post1521767.html#post1521767) posts and [full powercfg posts](https://bitsum.com/known-windows-power-guids/).
The general lack of complete [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/power-settings/configure-processor-power-management-options) about these things, the fact that the [Microsoft  PowerCfg](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/device-experiences/powercfg-command-line-options) documentation doesn't explain this, is the reason for this question.* This is also an extension of core parking answer [here](https://superuser.com/a/1435151/900431).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Reviewing Hidden Power GUID Options in Windows 10**

1. Run elevated cmd, compare results by exporting:

   ```
    powercfg /Q >%UserProfile%\Desktop\PowerPlanSettings.txt

    powercfg /Qh >%UserProfile%\Desktop\PowerPlanSettingsHidden.txt
   ```
2. Find more information on hidden GUID in question by searching the registry.

[image: Regedit-Search-Power-GUID]

3. To unhide GUID use the following format in elevated cmd, be sure to use sub group heading also, this will make it visible in the power options window, replace the sub group and GUID with the one from the /Qh log:

*Command Layout:*

```
    powercfg -attributes SUB-GROUP GUID -ATTRIB_HIDE
```

*Command Example:*

```
    powercfg -attributes SUB_PROCESSOR 8baa4a8a-14c6-4451-8e8b-14bdbd197537 -ATTRIB_HIDE
```

4. To rehide GUID use the following format commands in elevated cmd. Replace the sub group and GUID again.

*Command Layout:*

```
    powercfg -attributes SUB-GROUP GUID +ATTRIB_HIDE
```

*Command Example:*

```
    powercfg -attributes SUB_PROCESSOR 8baa4a8a-14c6-4451-8e8b-14bdbd197537 +ATTRIB_HIDE
```

5. (**WARNING: read user comments at end first, one user has had difficulties using this script**) Can [backup powerplan](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-configure-rename-backup-restore-power-plans-in-windows-7) then run powershell as admin, then run the
   `Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass`
   and use a script from GitHub to show all possible power config GUIDs in Windows using elevated Powershell:

> ```
> # List all possible power config GUIDs in Windows
> # Run: this-script.ps1 | Out-File powercfg.ps1
> # Then edit and run powercfg.ps1
> # (c) Pekka "raspi" Järvinen 2017
> ```

```
$powerSettingTable = Get-WmiObject -Namespace root\cimv2\power -Class Win32_PowerSetting
$powerSettingInSubgroubTable = Get-WmiObject -Namespace root\cimv2\power -Class Win32_PowerSettingInSubgroup

Get-WmiObject -Namespace root\cimv2\power -Class Win32_PowerSettingCapabilities | ForEach-Object {
  $tmp = $_.ManagedElement
  $tmp = $tmp.Remove(0, $tmp.LastIndexOf('{') + 1)
  $tmp = $tmp.Remove($tmp.LastIndexOf('}'))
  
  $guid = $tmp

  $s = ($powerSettingInSubgroubTable | Where-Object PartComponent -Match "$guid")

  if (!$s) {
    return
  }
  
  $tmp = $s.GroupComponent
  $tmp = $tmp.Remove(0, $tmp.LastIndexOf('{') + 1)
  $tmp = $tmp.Remove($tmp.LastIndexOf('}'))
  
  $groupguid = $tmp
  
  $s = ($powerSettingTable | Where-Object InstanceID -Match "$guid")
  
  $descr = [string]::Format("# {0}", $s.ElementName)
  $runcfg = [string]::Format("powercfg -attributes {0} {1} -ATTRIB_HIDE", $groupguid, $guid)
  
  Write-Output $descr
  Write-Output $runcfg
  Write-Output ""
  
}
```

Place in a text file and save as .ps1 file, then go to that folder in powershell and run the ./filename.ps1

Once output is printed run in PS admin run: Set-ExecutionPolicy Restricted to lock powershell again.

[GitHub Source](https://gist.github.com/raspi/203aef3694e34fefebf772c78c37ec2c)

- Run:  `./this-script.ps1`

Example Output:
`(Just Follow Sections 3 and 4 to Change the Output file as desired)`

```
# AHCI Link Power Management - HIPM/DIPM
powercfg -attributes 0012ee47-9041-4b5d-9b77-535fba8b1442 0b2d69d7-a2a1-449c-9680-f91c70521c60 -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Maximum Power Level
powercfg -attributes 0012ee47-9041-4b5d-9b77-535fba8b1442 51dea550-bb38-4bc4-991b-eacf37be5ec8 -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Turn off hard disk after
powercfg -attributes 0012ee47-9041-4b5d-9b77-535fba8b1442 6738e2c4-e8a5-4a42-b16a-e040e769756e -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Hard disk burst ignore time
powercfg -attributes 0012ee47-9041-4b5d-9b77-535fba8b1442 80e3c60e-bb94-4ad8-bbe0-0d3195efc663 -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Secondary NVMe Idle Timeout
powercfg -attributes 0012ee47-9041-4b5d-9b77-535fba8b1442 d3d55efd-c1ff-424e-9dc3-441be7833010 -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Primary NVMe Idle Timeout
powercfg -attributes 0012ee47-9041-4b5d-9b77-535fba8b1442 d639518a-e56d-4345-8af2-b9f32fb26109 -ATTRIB_HIDE

# AHCI Link Power Management - Adaptive
powercfg -attributes 0012ee47-9041-4b5d-9b77-535fba8b1442 dab60367-53fe-4fbc-825e-521d069d2456 -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Secondary NVMe Power State Transition Latency Tolerance
powercfg -attributes 0012ee47-9041-4b5d-9b77-535fba8b1442 dbc9e238-6de9-49e3-92cd-8c2b4946b472 -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Primary NVMe Power State Transition Latency Tolerance
powercfg -attributes 0012ee47-9041-4b5d-9b77-535fba8b1442 fc95af4d-40e7-4b6d-835a-56d131dbc80e -ATTRIB_HIDE

# JavaScript Timer Frequency
powercfg -attributes 02f815b5-a5cf-4c84-bf20-649d1f75d3d8 4c793e7d-a264-42e1-87d3-7a0d2f523ccd -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Slide show
powercfg -attributes 0d7dbae2-4294-402a-ba8e-26777e8488cd 309dce9b-bef4-4119-9921-a851fb12f0f4 -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Power Saving Mode
powercfg -attributes 19cbb8fa-5279-450e-9fac-8a3d5fedd0c1 12bbebe6-58d6-4636-95bb-3217ef867c1a -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Legacy RTC mitigations
powercfg -attributes 238c9fa8-0aad-41ed-83f4-97be242c8f20 1a34bdc3-7e6b-442e-a9d0-64b6ef378e84 -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Allow Away Mode Policy
powercfg -attributes 238c9fa8-0aad-41ed-83f4-97be242c8f20 25dfa149-5dd1-4736-b5ab-e8a37b5b8187 -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Sleep after
powercfg -attributes 238c9fa8-0aad-41ed-83f4-97be242c8f20 29f6c1db-86da-48c5-9fdb-f2b67b1f44da -ATTRIB_HIDE

# System unattended sleep timeout
powercfg -attributes 238c9fa8-0aad-41ed-83f4-97be242c8f20 7bc4a2f9-d8fc-4469-b07b-33eb785aaca0 -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Allow hybrid sleep
powercfg -attributes 238c9fa8-0aad-41ed-83f4-97be242c8f20 94ac6d29-73ce-41a6-809f-6363ba21b47e -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Hibernate after
powercfg -attributes 238c9fa8-0aad-41ed-83f4-97be242c8f20 9d7815a6-7ee4-497e-8888-515a05f02364 -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Allow system required policy
powercfg -attributes 238c9fa8-0aad-41ed-83f4-97be242c8f20 a4b195f5-8225-47d8-8012-9d41369786e2 -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Allow Standby States
powercfg -attributes 238c9fa8-0aad-41ed-83f4-97be242c8f20 abfc2519-3608-4c2a-94ea-171b0ed546ab -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Allow wake timers
powercfg -attributes 238c9fa8-0aad-41ed-83f4-97be242c8f20 bd3b718a-0680-4d9d-8ab2-e1d2b4ac806d -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Allow sleep with remote opens
powercfg -attributes 238c9fa8-0aad-41ed-83f4-97be242c8f20 d4c1d4c8-d5cc-43d3-b83e-fc51215cb04d -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Hub Selective Suspend Timeout
powercfg -attributes 2a737441-1930-4402-8d77-b2bebba308a3 0853a681-27c8-4100-a2fd-82013e970683 -ATTRIB_HIDE

# USB selective suspend setting
powercfg -attributes 2a737441-1930-4402-8d77-b2bebba308a3 48e6b7a6-50f5-4782-a5d4-53bb8f07e226 -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Setting IOC on all TDs
powercfg -attributes 2a737441-1930-4402-8d77-b2bebba308a3 498c044a-201b-4631-a522-5c744ed4e678 -ATTRIB_HIDE

# USB 3 Link Power Mangement
powercfg -attributes 2a737441-1930-4402-8d77-b2bebba308a3 d4e98f31-5ffe-4ce1-be31-1b38b384c009 -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Execution Required power request time-out
powercfg -attributes 2e601130-5351-4d9d-8e04-252966bad054 3166bc41-7e98-4e03-b34e-ec0f5f2b218e -ATTRIB_HIDE

# IO coalescing time-out
powercfg -attributes 2e601130-5351-4d9d-8e04-252966bad054 c36f0eb4-2988-4a70-8eee-0884fc2c2433 -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Processor Idle Resiliency Timer Resolution
powercfg -attributes 2e601130-5351-4d9d-8e04-252966bad054 c42b79aa-aa3a-484b-a98f-2cf32aa90a28 -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Deep Sleep Enabled/Disabled
powercfg -attributes 2e601130-5351-4d9d-8e04-252966bad054 d502f7ee-1dc7-4efd-a55d-f04b6f5c0545 -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Intel(R) Graphics Power Plan
powercfg -attributes 44f3beca-a7c0-460e-9df2-bb8b99e0cba6 3619c3f2-afb2-4afc-b0e9-e7fef372de36 -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Interrupt Steering Mode
powercfg -attributes 48672f38-7a9a-4bb2-8bf8-3d85be19de4e 2bfc24f9-5ea2-4801-8213-3dbae01aa39d -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Target Load
powercfg -attributes 48672f38-7a9a-4bb2-8bf8-3d85be19de4e 73cde64d-d720-4bb2-a860-c755afe77ef2 -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Unparked time trigger
powercfg -attributes 48672f38-7a9a-4bb2-8bf8-3d85be19de4e d6ba4903-386f-4c2c-8adb-5c21b3328d25 -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Lid close action
powercfg -attributes 4f971e89-eebd-4455-a8de-9e59040e7347 5ca83367-6e45-459f-a27b-476b1d01c936 -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Power button action
powercfg -attributes 4f971e89-eebd-4455-a8de-9e59040e7347 7648efa3-dd9c-4e3e-b566-50f929386280 -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Enable forced button/lid shut-down
powercfg -attributes 4f971e89-eebd-4455-a8de-9e59040e7347 833a6b62-dfa4-46d1-82f8-e09e34d029d6 -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Sleep button action
powercfg -attributes 4f971e89-eebd-4455-a8de-9e59040e7347 96996bc0-ad50-47ec-923b-6f41874dd9eb -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Lid open action
powercfg -attributes 4f971e89-eebd-4455-a8de-9e59040e7347 99ff10e7-23b1-4c07-a9d1-5c3206d741b4 -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Start menu power button
powercfg -attributes 4f971e89-eebd-4455-a8de-9e59040e7347 a7066653-8d6c-40a8-910e-a1f54b84c7e5 -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Link State Power Management
powercfg -attributes 501a4d13-42af-4429-9fd1-a8218c268e20 ee12f906-d277-404b-b6da-e5fa1a576df5 -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Processor performance increase threshold
powercfg -attributes 54533251-82be-4824-96c1-47b60b740d00 06cadf0e-64ed-448a-8927-ce7bf90eb35d -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Processor performance increase threshold for Processor Power Efficiency Class 1
powercfg -attributes 54533251-82be-4824-96c1-47b60b740d00 06cadf0e-64ed-448a-8927-ce7bf90eb35e -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Processor performance core parking min cores
powercfg -attributes 54533251-82be-4824-96c1-47b60b740d00 0cc5b647-c1df-4637-891a-dec35c318583 -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Processor performance core parking min. cores for Processor Power Efficiency Class 1
powercfg -attributes 54533251-82be-4824-96c1-47b60b740d00 0cc5b647-c1df-4637-891a-dec35c318584 -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Processor performance decrease threshold
powercfg -attributes 54533251-82be-4824-96c1-47b60b740d00 12a0ab44-fe28-4fa9-b3bd-4b64f44960a6 -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Processor performance decrease threshold for Processor Power Efficiency Class 1
powercfg -attributes 54533251-82be-4824-96c1-47b60b740d00 12a0ab44-fe28-4fa9-b3bd-4b64f44960a7 -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Initial performance for Processor Power Efficiency Class 1 when unparked
powercfg -attributes 54533251-82be-4824-96c1-47b60b740d00 1facfc65-a930-4bc5-9f38-504ec097bbc0 -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Processor performance core parking concurrency threshold
powercfg -attributes 54533251-82be-4824-96c1-47b60b740d00 2430ab6f-a520-44a2-9601-f7f23b5134b1 -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Processor performance core parking increase time
powercfg -attributes 54533251-82be-4824-96c1-47b60b740d00 2ddd5a84-5a71-437e-912a-db0b8c788732 -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Processor energy performance preference policy
powercfg -attributes 54533251-82be-4824-96c1-47b60b740d00 36687f9e-e3a5-4dbf-b1dc-15eb381c6863 -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Allow Throttle States
powercfg -attributes 54533251-82be-4824-96c1-47b60b740d00 3b04d4fd-1cc7-4f23-ab1c-d1337819c4bb -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Processor performance increase time for Processor Power Efficiency Class 1
powercfg -attributes 54533251-82be-4824-96c1-47b60b740d00 4009efa7-e72d-4cba-9edf-91084ea8cbc3 -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Processor performance decrease policy
powercfg -attributes 54533251-82be-4824-96c1-47b60b740d00 40fbefc7-2e9d-4d25-a185-0cfd8574bac6 -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Processor performance decrease policy for Processor Power Efficiency Class 1
powercfg -attributes 54533251-82be-4824-96c1-47b60b740d00 40fbefc7-2e9d-4d25-a185-0cfd8574bac7 -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Processor performance core parking parked performance state
powercfg -attributes 54533251-82be-4824-96c1-47b60b740d00 447235c7-6a8d-4cc0-8e24-9eaf70b96e2b -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Processor performance core parking parked performance state for Processor Power Efficiency Class 1
powercfg -attributes 54533251-82be-4824-96c1-47b60b740d00 447235c7-6a8d-4cc0-8e24-9eaf70b96e2c -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Processor performance boost policy
powercfg -attributes 54533251-82be-4824-96c1-47b60b740d00 45bcc044-d885-43e2-8605-ee0ec6e96b59 -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Processor performance increase policy
powercfg -attributes 54533251-82be-4824-96c1-47b60b740d00 465e1f50-b610-473a-ab58-00d1077dc418 -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Processor performance increase policy for Processor Power Efficiency Class 1
powercfg -attributes 54533251-82be-4824-96c1-47b60b740d00 465e1f50-b610-473a-ab58-00d1077dc419 -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Processor idle demote threshold
powercfg -attributes 54533251-82be-4824-96c1-47b60b740d00 4b92d758-5a24-4851-a470-815d78aee119 -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Processor performance core parking distribution threshold
powercfg -attributes 54533251-82be-4824-96c1-47b60b740d00 4bdaf4e9-d103-46d7-a5f0-6280121616ef -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Processor performance time check interval
powercfg -attributes 54533251-82be-4824-96c1-47b60b740d00 4d2b0152-7d5c-498b-88e2-34345392a2c5 -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Processor duty cycling
powercfg -attributes 54533251-82be-4824-96c1-47b60b740d00 4e4450b3-6179-4e91-b8f1-5bb9938f81a1 -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Processor idle disable
powercfg -attributes 54533251-82be-4824-96c1-47b60b740d00 5d76a2ca-e8c0-402f-a133-2158492d58ad -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Latency sensitivity hint min. unparked cores/packages
powercfg -attributes 54533251-82be-4824-96c1-47b60b740d00 616cdaa5-695e-4545-97ad-97dc2d1bdd88 -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Latency sensitivity hint min. unparked cores/packages for Processor Power Efficiency Class 1
powercfg -attributes 54533251-82be-4824-96c1-47b60b740d00 616cdaa5-695e-4545-97ad-97dc2d1bdd89 -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Latency sensitivity hint processor performance
powercfg -attributes 54533251-82be-4824-96c1-47b60b740d00 619b7505-003b-4e82-b7a6-4dd29c300971 -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Latency sensitivity hint processor performance for Processor Power Efficiency Class 1
powercfg -attributes 54533251-82be-4824-96c1-47b60b740d00 619b7505-003b-4e82-b7a6-4dd29c300972 -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Processor idle threshold scaling
powercfg -attributes 54533251-82be-4824-96c1-47b60b740d00 6c2993b0-8f48-481f-bcc6-00dd2742aa06 -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Processor performance core parking decrease policy
powercfg -attributes 54533251-82be-4824-96c1-47b60b740d00 71021b41-c749-4d21-be74-a00f335d582b -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Maximum processor frequency
powercfg -attributes 54533251-82be-4824-96c1-47b60b740d00 75b0ae3f-bce0-45a7-8c89-c9611c25e100 -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Maximum processor frequency for Processor Power Efficiency Class 1
powercfg -attributes 54533251-82be-4824-96c1-47b60b740d00 75b0ae3f-bce0-45a7-8c89-c9611c25e101 -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Processor idle promote threshold
powercfg -attributes 54533251-82be-4824-96c1-47b60b740d00 7b224883-b3cc-4d79-819f-8374152cbe7c -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Processor performance history count
powercfg -attributes 54533251-82be-4824-96c1-47b60b740d00 7d24baa7-0b84-480f-840c-1b0743c00f5f -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Processor performance history count for Processor Power Efficiency Class 1
powercfg -attributes 54533251-82be-4824-96c1-47b60b740d00 7d24baa7-0b84-480f-840c-1b0743c00f60 -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Processor performance decrease time for Processor Power Efficiency Class 1
powercfg -attributes 54533251-82be-4824-96c1-47b60b740d00 7f2492b6-60b1-45e5-ae55-773f8cd5caec -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Heterogeneous policy in effect
powercfg -attributes 54533251-82be-4824-96c1-47b60b740d00 7f2f5cfa-f10c-4823-b5e1-e93ae85f46b5 -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Minimum processor state
powercfg -attributes 54533251-82be-4824-96c1-47b60b740d00 893dee8e-2bef-41e0-89c6-b55d0929964c -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Minimum processor state for Processor Power Efficiency Class 1
powercfg -attributes 54533251-82be-4824-96c1-47b60b740d00 893dee8e-2bef-41e0-89c6-b55d0929964d -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Processor performance autonomous mode
powercfg -attributes 54533251-82be-4824-96c1-47b60b740d00 8baa4a8a-14c6-4451-8e8b-14bdbd197537 -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Heterogeneous thread scheduling policy
powercfg -attributes 54533251-82be-4824-96c1-47b60b740d00 93b8b6dc-0698-4d1c-9ee4-0644e900c85d -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Processor performance core parking over-utilisation threshold
powercfg -attributes 54533251-82be-4824-96c1-47b60b740d00 943c8cb6-6f93-4227-ad87-e9a3feec08d1 -ATTRIB_HIDE

# System cooling policy
powercfg -attributes 54533251-82be-4824-96c1-47b60b740d00 94d3a615-a899-4ac5-ae2b-e4d8f634367f -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Processor performance increase time
powercfg -attributes 54533251-82be-4824-96c1-47b60b740d00 984cf492-3bed-4488-a8f9-4286c97bf5aa -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Processor performance increase time for Processor Power Efficiency Class 1
powercfg -attributes 54533251-82be-4824-96c1-47b60b740d00 984cf492-3bed-4488-a8f9-4286c97bf5ab -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Processor idle state maximum
powercfg -attributes 54533251-82be-4824-96c1-47b60b740d00 9943e905-9a30-4ec1-9b99-44dd3b76f7a2 -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Processor performance level increase threshold for Processor Power Efficiency Class 1 processor count increase
powercfg -attributes 54533251-82be-4824-96c1-47b60b740d00 b000397d-9b0b-483d-98c9-692a6060cfbf -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Heterogeneous short running thread scheduling policy
powercfg -attributes 54533251-82be-4824-96c1-47b60b740d00 bae08b81-2d5e-4688-ad6a-13243356654b -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Maximum processor state
powercfg -attributes 54533251-82be-4824-96c1-47b60b740d00 bc5038f7-23e0-4960-96da-33abaf5935ec -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Maximum processor state for Processor Power Efficiency Class 1
powercfg -attributes 54533251-82be-4824-96c1-47b60b740d00 bc5038f7-23e0-4960-96da-33abaf5935ed -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Processor performance boost mode
powercfg -attributes 54533251-82be-4824-96c1-47b60b740d00 be337238-0d82-4146-a960-4f3749d470c7 -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Processor idle time check
powercfg -attributes 54533251-82be-4824-96c1-47b60b740d00 c4581c31-89ab-4597-8e2b-9c9cab440e6b -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Processor performance core parking increase policy
powercfg -attributes 54533251-82be-4824-96c1-47b60b740d00 c7be0679-2817-4d69-9d02-519a537ed0c6 -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Processor autonomous activity window
powercfg -attributes 54533251-82be-4824-96c1-47b60b740d00 cfeda3d0-7697-4566-a922-a9086cd49dfa -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Processor performance decrease time
powercfg -attributes 54533251-82be-4824-96c1-47b60b740d00 d8edeb9b-95cf-4f95-a73c-b061973693c8 -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Processor performance decrease time for Processor Power Efficiency Class 1
powercfg -attributes 54533251-82be-4824-96c1-47b60b740d00 d8edeb9b-95cf-4f95-a73c-b061973693c9 -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Processor performance core parking decrease time
powercfg -attributes 54533251-82be-4824-96c1-47b60b740d00 dfd10d17-d5eb-45dd-877a-9a34ddd15c82 -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Processor performance core parking utility distribution
powercfg -attributes 54533251-82be-4824-96c1-47b60b740d00 e0007330-f589-42ed-a401-5ddb10e785d3 -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Processor performance core parking max cores
powercfg -attributes 54533251-82be-4824-96c1-47b60b740d00 ea062031-0e34-4ff1-9b6d-eb1059334028 -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Processor performance core parking max. cores for Processor Power Efficiency Class 1
powercfg -attributes 54533251-82be-4824-96c1-47b60b740d00 ea062031-0e34-4ff1-9b6d-eb1059334029 -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Processor performance core parking concurrency headroom threshold
powercfg -attributes 54533251-82be-4824-96c1-47b60b740d00 f735a673-2066-4f80-a0c5-ddee0cf1bf5d -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Processor performance level decrease threshold for Processor Power Efficiency Class 1 processor count decrease
powercfg -attributes 54533251-82be-4824-96c1-47b60b740d00 f8861c27-95e7-475c-865b-13c0cb3f9d6b -ATTRIB_HIDE

# A floor performance for Processor Power Efficiency Class 0 when there are Processor Power Efficiency Class 1 processors unparked
powercfg -attributes 54533251-82be-4824-96c1-47b60b740d00 fddc842b-8364-4edc-94cf-c17f60de1c80 -ATTRIB_HIDE

# GPU preference policy
powercfg -attributes 5fb4938d-1ee8-4b0f-9a3c-5036b0ab995c dd848b2a-8a5d-4451-9ae2-39cd41658f6c -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Dim display after
powercfg -attributes 7516b95f-f776-4464-8c53-06167f40cc99 17aaa29b-8b43-4b94-aafe-35f64daaf1ee -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Turn off display after
powercfg -attributes 7516b95f-f776-4464-8c53-06167f40cc99 3c0bc021-c8a8-4e07-a973-6b14cbcb2b7e -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Console lock display off time-out
powercfg -attributes 7516b95f-f776-4464-8c53-06167f40cc99 8ec4b3a5-6868-48c2-be75-4f3044be88a7 -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Adaptive display
powercfg -attributes 7516b95f-f776-4464-8c53-06167f40cc99 90959d22-d6a1-49b9-af93-bce885ad335b -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Allow display required policy
powercfg -attributes 7516b95f-f776-4464-8c53-06167f40cc99 a9ceb8da-cd46-44fb-a98b-02af69de4623 -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Display brightness
powercfg -attributes 7516b95f-f776-4464-8c53-06167f40cc99 aded5e82-b909-4619-9949-f5d71dac0bcb -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Dimmed display brightness
powercfg -attributes 7516b95f-f776-4464-8c53-06167f40cc99 f1fbfde2-a960-4165-9f88-50667911ce96 -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Enable adaptive brightness
powercfg -attributes 7516b95f-f776-4464-8c53-06167f40cc99 fbd9aa66-9553-4097-ba44-ed6e9d65eab8 -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Standby Reserve Time
powercfg -attributes 8619b916-e004-4dd8-9b66-dae86f806698 468fe7e5-1158-46ec-88bc-5b96c9e44fd0 -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Standby Reset Percentage
powercfg -attributes 8619b916-e004-4dd8-9b66-dae86f806698 49cb11a5-56e2-4afb-9d38-3df47872e21b -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Non-sensor Input Presence Time-out
powercfg -attributes 8619b916-e004-4dd8-9b66-dae86f806698 5adbbfbc-074e-4da1-ba38-db8b36b2c8f3 -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Standby Budget Grace Period
powercfg -attributes 8619b916-e004-4dd8-9b66-dae86f806698 60c07fe1-0556-45cf-9903-d56e32210242 -ATTRIB_HIDE

# User Presence Prediction mode
powercfg -attributes 8619b916-e004-4dd8-9b66-dae86f806698 82011705-fb95-4d46-8d35-4042b1d20def -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Standby Budget Per Cent
powercfg -attributes 8619b916-e004-4dd8-9b66-dae86f806698 9fe527be-1b70-48da-930d-7bcf17b44990 -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Standby Reserve Grace Period
powercfg -attributes 8619b916-e004-4dd8-9b66-dae86f806698 c763ee92-71e8-4127-84eb-f6ed043a3e3d -ATTRIB_HIDE

# When sharing media
powercfg -attributes 9596fb26-9850-41fd-ac3e-f7c3c00afd4b 03680956-93bc-4294-bba6-4e0f09bb717f -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Video playback quality bias.
powercfg -attributes 9596fb26-9850-41fd-ac3e-f7c3c00afd4b 10778347-1370-4ee0-8bbd-33bdacaade49 -ATTRIB_HIDE

# When playing video
powercfg -attributes 9596fb26-9850-41fd-ac3e-f7c3c00afd4b 34c7b99f-9a6d-4b3c-8dc7-b6693b78cef4 -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Display brightness weight
powercfg -attributes de830923-a562-41af-a086-e3a2c6bad2da 13d09884-f74e-474a-a852-b6bde8ad03a8 -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Energy Saver Policy
powercfg -attributes de830923-a562-41af-a086-e3a2c6bad2da 5c5bb349-ad29-4ee2-9d0b-2b25270f7a81 -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Charge level
powercfg -attributes de830923-a562-41af-a086-e3a2c6bad2da e69653ca-cf7f-4f05-aa73-cb833fa90ad4 -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Critical battery notification
powercfg -attributes e73a048d-bf27-4f12-9731-8b2076e8891f 5dbb7c9f-38e9-40d2-9749-4f8a0e9f640f -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Critical battery action
powercfg -attributes e73a048d-bf27-4f12-9731-8b2076e8891f 637ea02f-bbcb-4015-8e2c-a1c7b9c0b546 -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Low battery level
powercfg -attributes e73a048d-bf27-4f12-9731-8b2076e8891f 8183ba9a-e910-48da-8769-14ae6dc1170a -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Critical battery level
powercfg -attributes e73a048d-bf27-4f12-9731-8b2076e8891f 9a66d8d7-4ff7-4ef9-b5a2-5a326ca2a469 -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Low battery notification
powercfg -attributes e73a048d-bf27-4f12-9731-8b2076e8891f bcded951-187b-4d05-bccc-f7e51960c258 -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Low battery action
powercfg -attributes e73a048d-bf27-4f12-9731-8b2076e8891f d8742dcb-3e6a-4b3c-b3fe-374623cdcf06 -ATTRIB_HIDE

# Reserve battery level
powercfg -attributes e73a048d-bf27-4f12-9731-8b2076e8891f f3c5027d-cd16-4930-aa6b-90db844a8f00 -ATTRIB_HIDE
```

---

*Note: When searching for the GUID's in the registry (taking the GUID from the /Qh command), one will also find collections of these GUID's in the registry. This is a place where additional entries can be found beyond the scope of the Powercfg /Qh output, for extra power and processor options in Windows 10. Review and edit with caution.*

---

**Further Research and Understanding:**

- [Microsoft - More Information on PowerCfg Command Line Options](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/device-experiences/powercfg-command-line-options)
- [Ten Forums - Export and Import Power Plan in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/43673-export-import-power-plan-windows-10-a.html)
- [Ten Forums - View All Power Plan Settings in a Text File](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/124566-view-all-power-plan-settings-text-file-windows.html)
- [Hexadecimal to Decimal Converter for Reviewing Tex Files](https://www.binaryhexconverter.com/hex-to-decimal-converter)
- [Notebook Review - How to Show Hidden Settings in Power Options](http://forum.notebookreview.com/threads/guide-power-options-power-plans-show-all-hidden-settings.767612/)
- [Copy Leaks - High Power Plan Comparison /Q and /Qh](https://copyleaks.com/compare-embed/compare-two-files/5a214c59-039b-455c-8294-d8277f8866af/10492545/3/11?key=j8zwjj2W3RYFsobwNc3Z)
- [Bitsum - Balanced Power Plan GUID's](https://bitsum.com/known-windows-power-guids/)
- [Microsoft - Example of Documentation on Some Processor GUID's](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/power-settings/configure-processor-power-management-options)
- [Microsoft Forum - Can Power Options be Copied to a File?](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/can-power-options-be-copied-to-a-file/4ce04a5c-ed39-4ad1-828d-931ad4d34f0d)

Comment: I ran `.\enable-all-advanced-power-settings.ps1 | Out-File powercfg.ps1` and then `.\powercfg.ps1` then my power settings says "your power plan information isn't available" and nothing showed up. Rebooting did not fix. oh god.

Comment: @Yvon there are some notes [here](https://gist.github.com/raspi/203aef3694e34fefebf772c78c37ec2c#gistcomment-3123028)of how to reset powerplan. Also [here](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-configure-rename-backup-restore-power-plans-in-windows-7) is how to import/backup plowerlans.

Comment: @Yvon, yep after testing, I get exactly the same out put as above. Let me know what your issue is. You should be about to [easily restore default power plans](https://winaero.com/restore-default-power-plans-windows-10/)

Comment: I waited for a whole day, not sure what I did but I tried with another tool plus booting and rebooting. Then everything showed up. Tool is here: https://forums.guru3d.com/threads/windows-power-plan-settings-explorer-utility.416058/

Comment: Even after I ran that program, I did not immediately saw all the options. I had to wait for a whole day.

Comment: All good @Yvon well everything above in this post only shows the GUID, you have to turn things on manually.

Comment: Yes I think your script generates `powercfg.ps1` which has `powercfg -attributes {0} {1} -ATTRIB_HIDE` in it. I'm sure I ran those lines properly.

Comment: @Yvon, I just get the print as provided in the post, there is no script generated. The commands could be added to a script afterwards, all this script does is print the variables, I would only turn on the variables that you require, otherwise you would have so many seetings you don't know what to do with them.

Comment: In the script, `Write-Output $runcfg` near the end of the loop writes the actual functioning commands into a new file. I just followed the comments in this script. Are you the author of this file? Anyway, I don't mind seeing many options I don't care about. I just want to see more options than the minimalist Microsoft wants me too see.

Comment: @Yvon Hmm, I don't know how I did not see that, no it is a github code. I have never noticed the script ever do anything more than output.  I can say on my test machine, after running that script nothing extra is in the power settings, only prints an output. But yes if you run the powerfg.ps1 that would indeed do this. I was only using it as an output for investigation purposes when looking at one specifically as it was hard to find information.

Comment: @ Yvon, added user warning to script.

Answer (score 4):

There is a more recent method posted here: [Answer by Kiaren Collis at Microsoft Community](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/csenabled-not-available/cb49f247-090a-40cb-905b-7fe2c18f6ea5?page=6)

```
$sting77 = "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\PowerSettings"
$querylist =  reg query $sting77
foreach ($regfolder in $querylist){
$querylist2 = reg query $regfolder
    foreach($2ndfolder in $querylist2){
    $active2 = $2ndfolder -replace "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE" , "HKLM:"
    Get-ItemProperty -Path $active2
    Set-ItemProperty -Path "$active2" -Name "Attributes" -Value '2'
    }
    $active = $regfolder -replace "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE" , "HKLM:"
    Get-ItemProperty -Path $active
    Set-ItemProperty -Path "$active" -Name "Attributes" -Value '2'
}
```

Basically, this script iterates over `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\PowerSettings` and changes all `Attributes` entries for all subfolders (will turn out to be subfolders in power settings) and all next-level subfolders (will turn out to be items in power settings).

Put this script to a Power Shell script and run it.

---

Additional information: I can never run the script in the community wiki answer successfully -- see my comments there, and once I run all the "powercfg" commands to "unhide" the settings, my power plan advanced settings breaks, and it says something like "Your Power plan information isn't available." and nothing shows up in the dialog.

There are posts providing various solutions to this problem, including resetting or duplicating the original power scheme using `powercfg`, and adding `CsEnabled` in the registry. I tried both, and neither worked for me.
Since Windows 10 version 2004, according to the same post I cited, `CsEnabled` entry is removed from registry.

---

In case you wonder why I care: All I need is to disable network when I put the computer to "sleep" or the S0 fake sleep -- use the entry "Networking connectivity in Standby" (screenshot below)

[image: Networking connectivity in Standby]

This is working as of Windows 10 version 21H2.

Answer (score 0):

Yvon,
If you're interested only in the "Networking connectivity in Standby" entry, here's a quick way to do this:
Open CMD as admin and run the following commands:

```
:: To unhide/show the setting in the Advanced Power Options GUI:
reg add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\PowerSettings\f15576e8-98b7-4186-b944-eafa664402d9" /f /v Attributes /t REG_DWORD /d 2

:: To modify the setting via registry:
reg add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\User\PowerSchemes\381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e\f15576e8-98b7-4186-b944-eafa664402d9" /f /v ACSettingIndex /t REG_DWORD /d 0

:: 0 = Disable
:: 1 = Enable
:: 2 = Managed by Windows
```

Answer (score 0):

this powershell script is the same as been proposed previously, but errors has been fixed. Worked for me latest win10, now every power settings option is visible and available to be edited from windows UI:

[image: all settings are unlocked now]

save it as file named `powercfg_unlock_settings.ps1`, paste this code inside and run it as administrator. If you can not run it, execute the first line command first: `Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned`

```
# Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned

$registry_path = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\PowerSettings"
$powercfg_settings = reg query $registry_path
$powercfg_settings_filtered = @($powercfg_settings) -match '.+' # no empty strings
foreach ($powercfg_setting in $powercfg_settings_filtered) {
    $powercfg_setting_formatted = $powercfg_setting -replace "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE" , "HKLM:"
    # Get-ItemProperty -Path $powercfg_setting_formatted
    Set-ItemProperty -Path $powercfg_setting_formatted -Name "Attributes" -Value "2" # 2=visible

    $powercfg_setting_children = reg query $powercfg_setting
    $escaped_regex = [regex]::Escape($powercfg_setting)
    $powercfg_setting_children_filtered = @($powercfg_setting_children) -match "$escaped_regex.+" # only children
    foreach($child_setting in $powercfg_setting_children_filtered) {
        $child_setting_formatted = $child_setting -replace "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE" , "HKLM:"
        # Get-ItemProperty -Path $child_setting_formatted
        Set-ItemProperty -Path $child_setting_formatted -Name "Attributes" -Value "2" # 2=visible
    }
}
```