# A powershell script to enable all advanced power options?

Tags: windows

I found one script on the internet, but it doesn't enable all of them. I am looking to enable the maximum CPU usage option and set it to around 80% to prevent the CPU from overheating on my laptop.

https://gist.github.com/raspi/203aef3694e34fefebf772c78c37ec2c

This doesn't enable Maximum processor frequency

Answer (score 1):

Here's a **PowerShell** script I wrote that lists all available POwer Options in a GridView control. Copy the entire script, paste into an *Administrative* **PowerShell** console, and press `<Enter>` to run:

```
Function Toggle-PowerSettingsVisibility {
    $Title         = 'Select option(s) to toggle visibility'
    $PowerSettings = 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\PowerSettings'
    @( [PSCustomObject]@{
            Attributes  = 0
            PSChildName = '{ -- No Changes -- }'
            Name        = ' "Safety" row to clear selection'
    } ) +
    @( Get-ChildItem $PowerSettings -Recurse | ? Property -contains 'Attributes' | Get-ItemProperty |
        Select Attributes, PSCHildName,
               @{ N = 'Name' ; E = { $_.FriendlyName.Split(',')[-1] }} ) | Sort PSChildName |
    Out-GridView -Passthru -Title $Title | ForEach {
        $Splat = @{
            Path  = Resolve-Path "$PowerSettings\*\$($_.PSChildName)"
            Name  = 'Attributes'
            Value = $_.Attributes -bXor 0x0000003 
        }
        Set-ItemProperty @Splat
    }
}
Toggle-PowerSettingsVisibility
```

THe `Attributes` column displays `2` for visible items and `1` for hidden items:
[image]

Type `Maximum` in the `Filter` textbox, select your desired option(s) and click `OK`:
[image]

That's it!

[image]

Comment: Set-ItemProperty : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
At line:18 char:26
+         Set-ItemProperty @Splat
+                          ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Set-ItemProperty], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetItemProp
   ertyCommand

Answer (score 0):

Taken from https://superuser.com/a/1689410

As an admin, this PowerShell script will unhide every power option in Power Options after running and restarting.

```ps
# Path to PowerSettings in Windows registry
# Set 'Attributes=2' to show in Power Options on each directory and subdirectory

$powerPath = "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\PowerSettings"
$powerQuery = reg query $powerPath
foreach ($regDir in $powerQuery) {

    $subPowerQuery = reg query $regDir
    foreach ($subDir in $subPowerQuery) {
        $subActive = $subDir -replace "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE" , "HKLM:"
        Get-ItemProperty -Path $subActive
        Set-ItemProperty -Path "$subActive" -Name "Attributes" -Value '2'
    }

    $active = $regDir -replace "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE" , "HKLM:"
    Get-ItemProperty -Path $active
    Set-ItemProperty -Path "$active" -Name "Attributes" -Value '2'
}
```

From there you can go

- Power & sleep
- Additional power settings
- Power Options / Change plan settings
- Change advanced power settings

Under the 'Processor power management' tree there are oodles of options. You may be looking for 'Maximum processor state' or another one, I'm not sure.

[windows power options dialog showing maximum processor state option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBa39.png)