# How can I read values set with powercfg /setdcvalueindex?

Tags: windows, sleep, hibernate, powercfg

The behavior of Windows Modern Standby's [adaptive hibernate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/power-settings/adaptive-hibernate) ostensibly depends on the following values:

> | Budget setting | Definition | Exposed as | Powercfg command |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | StandbyBudgetPercent | Defines the battery drain % that the user is allowed in a standby session. Default is 5%. | Power setting | `powercfg /setdcvalueindex scheme_current sub_presence standbybudgetpercent` |
> | ... |  |  |  |
> | StandbyReserveTime | Defines the screen on time, in seconds, that will be available to the user after standby exits and the screen turns on. Default is 1200 seconds. | Power setting | `powercfg /setdcvalueindex scheme_current sub_presence standbyreservetime` |

[The powercfg command-line options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/device-experiences/powercfg-command-line-options) don't include a corresponding `/getdcvalueindex` and `/query` does not seem to output StandbyBudgetPercent or StandbyReserveTime.

[StandbyBudgetPercent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/power-settings/standbybudgetpercent) includes the following:

> Windows provisioning path: Common\Power\Policy\Settings\AdaptivePowerBehavior\StandbyBudgetPercent
>
> Hidden setting: Yes

That path seems to apply to the creation of [provisioning packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/provisioning-packages/provisioning-how-it-works) which all seem to boil down to write operations on a system's configuration.  There doesn't seem to be any way to perform a read operation for that path.

Currently the only way I have to know anything about the current values on any given computer is the values that Microsoft publishes as defaults.  I suspect, though, that what is actually configured often differs from those defaults.  I'm also unsure whether `powercfg /setdcvalueindex` commands, in fact, set the value I expect since I currently have no way of reading back the value.

Modern standby and adaptive hibernate are already difficult to troubleshoot without having uncertainty about the values of the parameters it relies upon.

How can I positively assert the current value set by `powercfg /setdvalueindex`?

Answer (score 2):

The StandbyBudgetPercent and StandbyReserveTime power values are hidden
by default. You may list all power  values using the command `powercfg /Qh`
in an elevated CMD.

You will find more information in the post
[How to Access Hidden Power and Processor Options in Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1437851/how-to-access-hidden-power-and-processor-options-in-windows-10).

[Standby Budget Per Cent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/power-settings/standbybudgetpercent)
is specifically GUID `9fe527be-1b70-48da-930d-7bcf17b44990`.

[Standby Reserve Time](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/power-settings/standbyreservetime)
is specifically GUID `468fe7e5-1158-46ec-88bc-5b96c9e44fd0`.

Useful references :

- [Fine-Tune a Custom Power Plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/fine-tune-a-custom-power-plan-technicalreference?view=windows-11)
- [enable-all-advanced-power-settings.ps1](https://gist.github.com/raspi/203aef3694e34fefebf772c78c37ec2c)
- [POWERCFG to get AC index value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/315875/powercfg-to-get-ac-index-value)